# How to exclude all node_modules directories from gulp src stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, glob

My monorepo contains lots of `node_modules` directories. I want to clean all js files excluding those present in `node_modules` directory. Unfortunately, I can't make it work. Here're my tries with Gulp:

```js
import { src } from 'gulp';
import * as clean from 'gulp-clean';

const SRC_DIR = '../../apps/lambda/';

function clean() {
  return src([SRC_DIR + '**/*.js', '!' + SRC_DIR + '**/node_module/*.js'], {
    read: false,
  })
    .pipe(clean({ force: true }));
}
```

The above function deletes js files also from `node_modules` directory.

```
import { src } from 'gulp';
import * as clean from 'gulp-clean';
import * as ignore from 'gulp-ignore';

const SRC_DIR = '../../apps/lambda/';

function clean() {
  return src(SRC_DIR + '**/*.js', {
    read: false,
  })
    .pipe(ignore.exclude('**/node_module/*.js'))
    .pipe(clean({ force: true }));
}
```

Again, the same issue.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62708117/6910860

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. Globbing also needs to exclude parent directory. Here's the correct code:

```js
import { src } from 'gulp';
import * as clean from 'gulp-clean';

const SRC_DIR = '../../apps/lambda/';

function clean() {
  return src(
    [
      SRC_DIR + '**/*.js',
      '!' + SRC_DIR + '**/node_modules/',
      '!' + SRC_DIR + '**/node_modules/**/*.js',
    ],
    {
      read: false,
    }
  ).pipe(clean({ force: true }));
}
```